Apache Derby and Netbeans ClientDriver cannot be found
Trying to use Netbeans 21, Derby 10.16.1.1 to create a database and DAO related things.
I've created some files to do DAO things, but I consistently get this error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.client.ClientDriver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:421)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:412)

In the project properties --> libraries,

I have derbyclient, derby, and derbyshared. In the JavaDB (Network) driver in the Database drivers,
I have derbyshared, derby, and derbyclient. The driver class is
org.apache.derby.client.ClientAutoloadedDriver.

I tried to reinstall Derby, but that didn't work.
